# How to search for YouTube videos over a specific subset of channels?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get a list of all videos associated with a specific search term from a subset of channels. The subset of channels is:

- https://www.youtube.com/user/minutephysics
- https://www.youtube.com/user/AsapSCIENCE
- https://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy

For example, if I search for the term `force`, I want all YouTube videos related to that search term from the above 3 channels to appear in the results.

How can I do this using the YouTube Data API's [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint? The argument for `author` mentioned in the [explainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOEAD-gfJ_M) seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, you have at your disposal the following request parameter:

> [**`channelId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) (string)
>
> The `channelId` parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created by the channel.
>
> **Note:** Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the `channelId` parameter and sets the [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter value to `video`, but it does not also set one of the [forContentOwner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forContentOwner), [forDeveloper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forDeveloper), or [forMine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) filters.

Given the above specification, you'll have to call `Search.list` three times, passing to each invocation of it one of the ID of the channels of your interest.

Note that the neither of channel user names `minutephysics`, `AsapSCIENCE` and `khanacademy` is a valid channel ID, but that's easily resolvable:

```bash
$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name minutephysics
UCUHW94eEFW7hkUMVaZz4eDg

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name AsapSCIENCE
UCC552Sd-3nyi_tk2BudLUzA

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name khanacademy
UC4a-Gbdw7vOaccHmFo40b9g
```

Above I made use of my public (MIT licensed) Python 3 script [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de); this script is able to search the API for custom URLs and respectively query the API for user names.

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)